# Is there a driver that should be installed for a Logitech G332 SE Gaming HEADSET?

Tags: drivers, headset, logitech-headset

I purchased a **LOGITECH G332 SE** gaming headset from Vatan Bilgisayar, Ankara, Turkey today and I want to ask if it has a driver which should be installed.

Comment: Logitech site does not have any drivers for that product>>>>>>>https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024690794--Downloads-G332-Gaming-Headset

Comment: It is for g322 not g332 se

Comment: They don't have any for that model either....